# Powershell script to copy file from Primary PC to users disaster recovery PC

Tags: powershell

I am looking to create a PowerShell script to copy a file from a users primary PC to the users Disaster Recovery PC. This is going to be done for over 100 people so I was going to create txt file with the users Production PC names and a list with their recovery PC names. Not sure how to match the PCs up for two different list. The file name always begins with the users domain account (username.Primary) and I am not sure how to specify the username part since it changes for each user.

```
$ServerListProd = Get-Content "C:\path\computers.txt"

$ServerlistRecovery = Get-Content "C:\path\computers2.txt"

$SourceFileLocation = "c:\path\username.primary"

$Destination = "c:\path\"

foreach ($_ in $ServerList)

{Copy-Item $SourceFileLocation -Destination \\$serverlistd\$Destination -Recurse -PassThru}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put everything in one CSV and than Import it to Powershell.

CSV could look like this:

```
Primary;Recovery1;Recovery2;Recovery3
user1.Primary;user1.Recovery1;user1.Recovery2;user1.Recovery3;
user2.Primary;user2.Recovery1;user2.Recovery2;user2.Recovery3;
user3.Primary;user3.Recovery1;user3.Recovery2;user3.Recovery3;
user4.Primary;user4.Recovery1;user4.Recovery2;user4.Recovery3;
user5.Primary;user5.Recovery1;user5.Recovery2;user5.Recovery3;
```

Now you can Import it to powershell and have the data in an array:

```
$pc = Import-Csv "path to CSV" -Delimiter ";"
```